# How to rewrite query to work without WITH syntax

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

just looking for some help on how to rewrite this query without WITH.
Im aware that i need to replace references to WITH-subqueries with the body of the subquery but im not exactly sure how. Thanks.

```
WITH current_employees AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT emp_id
    FROM appointment
    WHERE end_date IS NULL
),
appointments_2015 AS (
    SELECT a.emp_id, salary,
        CASE WHEN start_date < '2015-01-01' THEN '2015-01-01' ELSE start_date END AS start_date,
        CASE WHEN end_date < '2016-01-01' THEN end_date ELSE '2015-12-31' END AS end_date
    FROM appointment a
        JOIN current_employees ce ON a.emp_id = ce.emp_id
    WHERE start_date < '2016-01-01' AND (end_date >= '2015-01-01' OR end_date IS NULL)
)
SELECT
    emp_id,
    SUM( salary * (end_date - start_date + 1) / 365 ) AS total
FROM appointments_2015
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Comment: Hi, please provide us with some test data and desired output. And tag the database you're on please as well

Comment: Why do you need to remove the common table expression? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: An explanation of what the code should be doing would also help.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the CTEs are only referenced once, the change is pretty straight forward. For each CTE create a derived table (sometimes referred to as "inline view" or simply sub-select)

```
SELECT
    emp_id,
    SUM( salary * (end_date - start_date + 1) / 365 ) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT a.emp_id, salary,
      CASE WHEN start_date < '2015-01-01' THEN '2015-01-01' ELSE start_date END AS start_date,
      CASE WHEN end_date < '2016-01-01' THEN end_date ELSE '2015-12-31' END AS end_date
  FROM appointment a
      JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT emp_id
        FROM appointment
        WHERE end_date IS NULL
      ) current_employees ce ON a.emp_id = ce.emp_id
  WHERE start_date < '2016-01-01' AND (end_date >= '2015-01-01' OR end_date IS NULL)
) appointments_2015 
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the salary in 2015 for current employees.  If so:

```
SELECT a.emp_id,
       SUM( salary * (end_date_2015 - start_date_2015 + 1) / 365 ) AS total
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             (CASE WHEN start_date < '2015-01-01' THEN '2015-01-01'
                   WHEN start_date < '2016-01-01' THEN start_date
              END) AS start_date_2015,
             (CASE WHEN end_date < '2015-01-01' THEN NULL
                   WHEN end_date < '2016-01-01' THEN end_date
                   ELSE '2015-12-31'
              END) AS end_date
      FROM appointments_2015 a
     ) a
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING COUNT(end_date) <> COUNT(*);
```